# Selenium Automation unable to click the link

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, css-selectors

I am trying to automate some task for a website. In on page there  is a option to "Move to next page" its not usual a link but when I click it takes me to the next page. The code is given below. I tried all possible ways to locate it by id, classname, xpath and css selector none of them are working. Please help me to find the way for cases with javascript:void(0). I tried the methods from some other stackoverflow questions asked by others...those are also not working.

```
WebElement skip = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='javascript:void[0]']"));
skip.click();
```

Comment: Source code:<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="someclassname"> ::before "Move to next page"  == $0</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the `<a>` and use filter on the text "Move to next page" to locate the element you're after, unless you have multiple elements with that text.

Also check if the id is unique, if there are more than one element with that id, it returns the first hit. You can use jQuery regex match to find them all, and find a way to locate that element.

**EDIT:** with the source code you provided:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="someclassname"> ::before "Move to next page" == $0</a>
```

Ignore those `$0` & `::before` that are obviously copied from the developer console of the browser, it should be something like this:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="someclassname">Move to next page</a>
```

So, in Selenium, you can locate it with:

```
String jsScript = "return $('a.someclassname:visible').filter(function () { return $(this).text() == 'Move to next page'; });";
Object object = ((JavascriptExecutor)this.driver).executeScript(jsScript, new Object[0]);
if (WebElement.class.isInstance(object))
{
    return (WebElement) object;
}
if (List.class.isInstance(object))
{
    return (WebElement) ((List)object).stream().filter(WebElement.class::isInstance).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
return null;
```

Comment: <a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="someclassname"> ::before == $0 "Move to next page"</a>  There is no unique id

Comment: @Anu, I have edited the answer, please give it a try, and share what you find.

Comment: hi is it possible to locate with java. I am using selenium with java in eclipse

Comment: the example I posted above is Java.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these methods should work

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Move to next page"));
element.isEnabled();
element.click();

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Move to next page"));
element.isEnabled();
element.click();
```

Comment: I tried that. it gives me no such element exception .  The thing i find unusual is a href = "javascript:void(0)" . this is something i have not come across,,, iam new to coding.

Comment: Try just giving  //a in firefinder plugin in Firefox and see what are the other unique attributes you have to locate this element.

Comment: I am using chrome.  One more information i can give is all these things are a part of the iFrame. The onclick link is also not given as it seems to be hidden

Comment: Now that you say it's part of an Iframe, I am sure you are switching the focus to the Frame. If not, try switching the focus to the iFrame and then perform the click.

driver.switchTo().frame(getIframe().getAttribute("id"));
     isSwitchedToIframe = true;
     setIframeUrl(driver.getCurrentUrl());

Answer (score 0):

Use below `xpath` to click on-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='someclassname'][contains(text(),'Move to next page')]")).click();
```

Comment: Please see my post I had corrected it now.     ::before  "Move to next page" == $0  what does it mean?  in that case "Move to next page" is not a text right